# ExpandableListView & sub-activity

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm new in Android world and I have the following scenario:

I have an Activity main.xml RelativeLayout and within an ExpandableListView.

When I expand a group it will show me the content for the child: this is example.xml.

Now I have on the example.xml-layout 1 Button with the id btn_send, my question is how I can access the button?

I tried to access the button via Example.java  I get an error the btn_send cannot be found.  and I tried through Main.java I get the some error.

Thank you in advance,

BR
Ali

```
public class Main extends Activity {

ExpandableListView exv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    exv = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.exv_main);
    exv.setAdapter(new MainAdapter(this));
    exv.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

        int previousGroup = -1;

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            if(groupPosition != previousGroup)
                exv.collapseGroup(previousGroup);
            previousGroup = groupPosition;
        }
    });

}
}
```

In the MainAdapter class

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(context);
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);


    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams llpImage = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.TOP);


        switch (groupPosition){

            case 0:

                layout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(childList[groupPosition][childPosition], null);


            break;

            case 1:

            break; 
            case 2:

                break; 
        }
        return layout;
}
```

and the main.xml

```
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/exv_main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="#CDCDD0"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:listSelector="#CDCDD0"
    android:dividerHeight="1dip"
    android:cacheColorHint="#CDCDD0"
    android:childDivider="#CDCDD0"
    >
</ExpandableListView>
```

and in the example.xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_send"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="send" />
```

and in the Example.java

public class Example extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.example);

    final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);    

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {      
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            btn.setText("huhu");
        }
    }); 
}
}
```

Comment: Please post your code snippet and the XML layout.

Comment: @AndreaCarrer thank you for you answer. But I dont know how I can paste my code snippets :-( it to long!

Comment: Paste the most relevant parts of your code, the ones connected with btn_send object.

Comment: @Ali next time try editing your question and add the code there..

Comment: I've put it for you this time; Remember to put it yourself next time as @Kuba said.

Comment: @KubaSpatny & Andrea Carrer thank you very much and this was my first post becuase of that. thanks again :-)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to set an onClickListener to your button in your getChildView method:

```
public class MyExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private final SparseArray<Group> groups;
    public Activity activity;
    public LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyExpandableAdapter(Activity activity, SparseArray<Group> groups) {
        this.groups = groups;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean  isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
          convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout_details, null);
        }
        TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        text.setText("content");

        Button b = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // implement functionality

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }    

}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I have here  more than one layout in a switch-case so how I can do that? thank you

Comment: @Ali Oh yeah I see, I answered it before you posted that code. However I am in class right now so I won't be able to answer your comment right away..

Comment: no problem thanks for your help, & I will try if I solve it I will tell you, otherwise u can suggest your solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

@Kuba Spatny thank you for you help and I solve my problem as below code... Maybe there other way too to solve it but this is my solution:

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater; 

    switch (groupPosition) {
    case 0:
        if (convertView == null) {
            inflater  = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(childLayout[groupPosition][childPosition], null);
            Button btn1 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
            btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(context, ExampTest1.class));
                            }
                        });
            }



        break;
    case 1:
            inflater  = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(childLayout[groupPosition][childPosition], null);
            Button btn1 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
            btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(context, ExampTest2.class));
                            }
                        });
        break;
    case 2:
        if (convertView == null) {
            inflater  = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(childLayout[groupPosition][childPosition], null);
            Button btn1 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
            btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(context, ExampTest3.class));
                            }
                        });
        break;
    }

    return convertView;
}
```